# android add multiple phone numbers for a contact

Tags: android, insert, contacts

using Android SDK > 5, I m creating a contact by starting the ACTION_INSERT activity.
I want to add several phone numbers (work, home, etc...) for the contact using the following code:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, 
          ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 

for(ContactInfo.Phone p : phones)
      {

       newIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, p.number);
       newIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_ISPRIMARY, p.isPrimary ? new Integer(1) : null);
       newIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, unconvertPhoneType(p.type));

      }
```

(unconvertPhoneType() is a function to get the type as CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_XXX)

I have just one example being inserted in the contact.
What is wrong with the above?

Additionally, in LogCat logs, I have also the following error:

> 12-14 11:09:03.015: WARN/Bundle(1724): Key phone_type expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value  was returned.

looks like it comes from PHONE_TYPE, however CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_XXX is of type integer, so i am not sure...
What is the cause of that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The logcat is telling you that it was expecting a String value, not an integer.  That is your problem.  The phone number should be of type String.

I pulled this example from the official documentation, and you can see the phone number is represented as a String with "".

```
// Add a phone number for Abraham Lincoln.  Begin with the URI for
// the new  record     just returned by insert(); it ends with the _ID
// of the new record, so we don't have to add the ID ourselves.
// Then append the designation for the phone table to this URI,
// and use the resulting URI to insert the phone number.
phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
values.clear(); 
values.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE); 
values.put(People.Phones.NUMBER, "1233214567");
getContentResolver().insert(phoneUri, values);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ContactInfo.Phone.number IS a String, therefore it's not the issue. Please note I'm inserting the contact through an Intent, not inserting directly the contact as the code snippet you provided shows. Thanks though.